# How to add time in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to calculate total hrs spend by an employee between 09:00am and 18:00pm.

My database look like this.

How can I do this??

```
AttendanceId     EmpId           CheckTime                  CheckType
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3               5             2013-01-03 09:00:15.000           1 (Login)
   4               5             2013-01-03 11:00:00.000           2 (Logout)
   5               5             2013-01-03 11:30:00.000           1 
   6               5             2013-01-03 13:00:00.000           2 
   7               5             2013-01-03 13:30:00.000           1 
   8               5             2013-01-03 16:00:00.000           2 
   9               5             2013-01-03 16:30:00.000           1 
  10               5             2013-01-03 18:00:00.000           2
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: frankly speaking my idea was to add  all the login time and logout time and then subtract total logout time from total login time.But unfortunately '+' operator is not supported in time format..

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for SQL Server 2008 that's relevant to date arithmetic, specifically the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function? That should give you what you need.

Comment: For one employee or all employees?  Over what period?  What is a "day"?  What if someone works past midnight?  Are you trying to get a summary for each 24 hour day, e.g. if someone works 4 hours, breaks for dinner, and logs in again at 19:00 does that count as 9 hours worked if you check at midnight?

Comment: Your task would be a lot simpler if you had been using a stored procedure to insert new rows, with an automatic calculation of the elapsed time since the last entry...  Then you'd have a column with hours spent which you'd just need to total.

Comment: @1.618 - Or if the table represented sessions rather than events, i.e. had columns for `LoginTime` and `LogoutTime` so that the pairing, if any, is already taken care of.  (Golden user name, eh?)

Comment: i just want to calculate total hrs spend by the employee(empid-5) between 09:00am-18:00pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `Login`/`Logout` values are in the same column, this might be easier to `PIVOT` the login/logout times first then get the `datediff` to determine the total amount of time an employee is present.

The `PIVOT` portion of the query is this:

```
select empid, [1], [2]
from
(
  select empid, checktime, checktype,
    row_number() over(partition by empid, checktype order by checktime) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(checktime)
  for checktype in ([1], [2])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e94f3/3)

The result of this is:

```
| EMPID |                              1 |                              2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     5 | January, 03 2013 09:00:15+0000 | January, 03 2013 11:00:00+0000 |
|     5 | January, 03 2013 11:30:00+0000 | January, 03 2013 13:00:00+0000 |
|     5 | January, 03 2013 13:30:00+0000 | January, 03 2013 16:00:00+0000 |
|     5 | January, 03 2013 16:30:00+0000 | January, 03 2013 18:00:00+0000 |
```

Once the data is in this structure, you can easily get the difference in the time by applying the [`DateDiff()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

The final query to generate the amount of time an employee is logged in is:

```
select empid, sum(SecondsDiff) / 3600 as TotalHours
from
(
  select empid, datediff(ss, [1], [2]) SecondsDiff
  from
  (
    select empid, checktime, checktype,
      row_number() over(partition by empid, checktype order by checktime) rn
    from yourtable
  ) src
  pivot
  (
    max(checktime)
    for checktype in ([1], [2])
  ) piv
) src
group by empid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0dab2/9)

And the result is:

```
| EMPID | TOTALHOURS |
----------------------
|     5 |          7 |
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference between two dates, you use the `DATEDIFF` function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

I think you'd need to do this row-by-row, though.  Because of the structure of your table, you can't just do a simple query.